# Context-sensitive grammar prolog

Tags: prolog, dcg

I'm trying to write a DCG grammar in Prolog that would do this :

```
kkk ... k --> N * (k)
```

Where `k` could be anything (e.g. "a", "ab", "abc").

On the left is what I want to consume, on the right is what I want to generate.

Is this even possible with DCG ?

I was trying to do the simplest case with only a letter, like so:

```
s(N) --> a(N).
a(0) --> [].
a(R) --> [R], [*], [a].
a(M) --> [a], a(N), {M is N + 1}.

eval(X) :-
   s(_, X, []).
```

But I'm not sure this is the correct way.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Afaik, this probably requires a context-*sensitive* grammar, which is less straightforward.

Comment: Yep, I know (that's why I put it in the title), but how would I do this in prolog ?

Comment: What would you want the result of `kkkkkmmm` to be? Do you only want to recognize an integral, single repeated sequence? By the way, for DCG, you should use `phrase`, thus: `eval(X, R * (K)) :- phrase(s(R, K), X).` where your DCG would provide not just the count but the repeated subsequence, `K`.

Comment: I would like it to be `kkkkkmmm => 5*k 3*m`, but I know that from what I'm asking it could be  `kkkkkmmm => 1*kkkkkmmm` which is not really factorized. I'm trying to factorize Structural Information Theory sequences.

Comment: That's where it gets interesting. The logical rules for expected results are a bit fuzzy, so it's hard to answer the question. Are "unfactorized" results allowed? And what does "unfactorized" really mean? Is `kkkmmmkkkmmm => 2 * kkkmmm` unfactorized? Or does it need to look like `3*k 3*m 3*k 3*m`? Or `2*(3*k 3*m)`?

Comment: Exactly, this gets fuzzy really quick and I'm still figuring out what the most factorized version of a sequence is. In fact, unfactorized results are allowed when you can't factorize further.

Comment: Wouldn't an unfactorized result, by definition, be able to be factorized further? If not, what's the definition of factorized versus unfactorized?

Comment: My bad, I didn't day it properly. When I said unfactorized I was thinking of, for example : `abcdefg`, which is in fact  already in its most  factorized possible way, my bad :)